# Is it possible to shorten object names in c#?

Tags: c#

I've looked far and wide, and haven't found a mention on what I try to do, so I'm kind of afraid it could be impossible. But I think it's worth a try.

I have an object, which is a part of a class put in another class, which is global. It looks like that:

```
public struct descrptiveButLongName
    { public static GameData relativelyLongName {get; set;} }

class GameData
    { public playerData notSoShortNameToo {get; set;} }
```

I'm referencing the descriptiveButLongName.relativelyLongName.notSoShortNameToo quite often in my code (that's basically a player object in a game), and it takes really, really large amount of space. I was trying to find a way to make some shorthand for that particular property, so I could just name it for example PlayerData. Something to the effect of:

```
using PlayerData = FileName.descriptiveButLongName.relativelyLongName.notSoShortNameToo;
```

but with aliasing an actual objects, not a type name, while still having the ability to keep descriptive names. Is this even possible in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all there is something that is called a Law of Demeter which, shortly speaking says "Only talk to your immediate friends."

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

The fundamental notion is that a given object should assume as little as possible about the structure or properties of anything else (including its subcomponents), in accordance with the principle of "information hiding".

In your case if you would apply this principle (which I strongly recommend to), even if your property names would be long you wouldn't have this problem.

Second of all: you are right you can use "using" directives for aliasing types and namespaces but not for certain properties.

What you could though do as some kind of a workaround is to create a special property that in it's "get" accessor takes out the whole chain, but this would then break the Law Of Demeter.

Comment: +100 for Law of Demeter! Long names is code smell and suggest you are doing things wrong.

Comment: Didn't know the name Law of Demeter, but I actually try to hold to such principles (I'm self-learned, so it's not always easy!) - but in this particular case, it's my own project and I'm referencing a very basic object (the player is pretty much necessary where he is now), so I don't think I will run into problems.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a property that gets this object for you:

```
public GameData pData
{
    get { return FileName.descriptiveButLongName.relativelyLongName.notSoShortNameToo; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While aliasing like this is not possible in C#, why not make your own life easier by making shortcut properties for it yourself?

```
class FileName {
    public GameData notSoShortName {
        get {
            return this.descriptiveButLongName.relativeLongName.notSoShortName;
        }
    }
}
```

Life is a convenience if you make it so... the compiler will just optimize it all away into the same code anyway, so there's not even a performance penalty.

Comment: Unlike Rotem you forgot Property type

Comment: You are right this is possible but breaks the Law of Demeter, so it's not a recommended practice.

Comment: @BrunoCosta fixed, thnx